# How can I fill in frontend the ID for deleting a user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't delete the one which I select on the page. It deletes every time the first one on the list.

I don't know if it has anything to do with the backend. If that's the case you have to tell me, then I would take it in with me in the backend.

My UserManagement.js:

```
function UserManagement({ history }) {
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin);
  const userList = useSelector((state) => state.userList);
  const { loading  } = userLogin;
  const { users} = userList;

 
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  },[dispatch, history]);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      dispatch(deleteUserAction(id));
    }
  };

  
  console.log(userList);
  console.log(users);
  return (
    <MainScreen title={`List of Users`}>
       <Link to="/createUser" id="OpenCreateUserDialogButton">
        <Button style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginBottom: 6 }} size="lg">
          Create new User
        </Button>
      </Link>
      
      {loading && <Loading />}
     
      {users &&
        users?.map((users) => (
         
          <Accordion>
            <Card style={{ margin: 10 }} key={users._id}>
              <Card.Header style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <span
                  // onClick={() => ModelShow(note)}
                  style={{
                    color: "black",
                    textDecoration: "none",
                    flex: 1,
                    cursor: "pointer",
                    alignSelf: "center",
                    fontSize: 18,
                  }}
                >
                      
                      {users.userID}               
                </span>
                <div>
                  <Link to="/profileedit">
                    <Button
                    id="EditButton"
                    >Edit</Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Button
                      id="DeleteButton"
                      variant="danger"
                      className="mx-2"
                      onClick={() => deleteHandler(users.id)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </div>
              </Card.Header>
```

And this is my userAction:

```
  export const deleteUserAction = (_id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_DELETE_REQUEST,
      });
  
      const {
        userLogin: { userInfo },
      } = getState();
  
      const url = "http://localhost:8080/user/:id";
  
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token.token}`,
        },
      };
      console.log(userInfo.token.token);
      const { data } = await axios.delete(url, config);
  
      dispatch({
        type: USER_DELETE_SUCCESS,
        payload: data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      const message =
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      dispatch({
        type: USER_DELETE_FAIL,
        payload: message,
      });
    }
  };
```

The backend:

```
exports.deleteUser = async (request, response) => {
  try{
      await User.findByIdAndDelete({_id: request.params.id});
      response.status(201).json("User deleted Successfully");
  } catch (error){
      response.status(409).json({ message: error.message});     
  }
}
```

The error which been showed by Chrome network

> {"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: ':id' }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "user""

Comment: Can you check if the id that is being sent to the backend actually is the one that you have selected?

Comment: try deleteHandler(users._id)

Comment: I got an error .. in chrome network I can show you I will edit it to my answer

Comment: @Areg how can I check this. It doesn´t work right .. because it takes not the id of the user which been selected .. it should be this way http://localhost:8080/{id of the user} but it´s that way http://localhost:8080/:id .. and that is crashing

Comment: `console.log(request.params.id)`

Comment: @Areg in backend it shows me up the id if I delete not in frontend

Comment: @acbay yeah how can I put it in that´s the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your axios request you are missing the id when setting up the url, since your backend picks up the id by the request params.

This

```
const url = "http://localhost:8080/user/:id";
```

Should be this

```
const url = `http://localhost:8080/user/${_id}`;
```

Comment: it works thanks I did it that way const url = "http://localhost:8080/user/"+_id